# Password/Calculator in C#

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and using C# and I am trying to create a program that asks the user for a password and you should have 3 attempts to get it right but I don't know how to add a counter variable or an error message.  Can someone help me out?

Also the main part of my program is having the user to choose 2 numbers and having them either subtracted, multiplied, added or divided but my code just automatically does that instead of asking the user.  Can anyone help me out with this please?

Here is my code:

```
    static string userName = "";
    static string passWord = "";
    static float numberOne = 0;
    static float numberTwo = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        getpassWord();
        validatepassWord();
        calculatorIntro();
        getData();
        calcAddition();
        calcSubtraction();
        calcDivision();
        calcMultiplication();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void getpassWord()
    {
        while (passWord == "")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the password > ");
            passWord = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static void validatepassWord()
    {
        if (passWord == "12345")
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a valid password > ");
            passWord = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

   static void calculatorIntro()
   {
       Console.Write("Please enter your name > ");
       userName = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}, Welcome to the Calculator!", userName);
       Console.WriteLine("After you have entered the password, you must then enter 2 numbers and decide whether they should be added, multiplied, subtracted or divided");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
    static void getData()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the first number");
        numberOne = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter the second number");
        numberTwo = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    static void calcAddition()
    {
        Console.Write("{0} + {1} = {2}", numberOne, numberTwo, numberOne + numberTwo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void calcSubtraction()
    {
        Console.Write("{0} - {1} = {2}", numberOne, numberTwo, numberOne - numberTwo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void calcDivision()
    {
        Console.Write("{0} / {1} = {2}", numberOne, numberTwo, numberOne / numberTwo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void calcMultiplication()
    {
        Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2}", numberOne, numberTwo, numberOne * numberTwo);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: There are a number of separate questions here. Try to solve them one by one. Ask new questions as needed, but for things like *I don't know how to add a counter variable or an error message* - there are definitely already tutorials out there.

Comment: Sorry @Yuck I have been stuck on this program for a while and just needed a straight answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the password validation:
Use a do while loop. The condition to terminate would be if the counter reaches three or if the user gets it right.
example

```
int counter = 0;
boolean passwordCorrect = false;
do {
    Console.Write("Please enter the password > ");
    passWord = Console.ReadLine();

    //If the password is correct,then it will break the loop
    if (passWord == "1234") {
       passwordCorrect = true;
    }
    counter++;
} while (counter < 3 && !passwordCorrect);
```

You are not even asking the user if they want to subtract, add,etc.For that, ask the user in the main method. Then you will call that method depending on what they inputed.

Example.

```
int choice;
Console.Write("What operation would you like to perform?\n1. Addition\2. Subtraction");
Console.Write("\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division");
choice = Console.ReadLine();

switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        calcAddition();
        break;
    case 2:
        calcSubtraction();
        break;
    case 3:
        calcMultiplication();
        break;
    case 4:
        calcDivision();
        break;
    default:
        Console.Writeline("No operation chosen");
        break;
}
```

Comment: your loop logic is not correct. `||` will short-circuit on the first `true`, so even if they enter the correct PW on the first try, it would go around again. You probably want `&&`.

Comment: Or simply reverse them.  Check the password first then check the counter.

Comment: You are correct. My loop was wrong. I will change it. Thanks for the catch

Comment: Thank you @flaco for your answers - I am new to c# and not very good at it to be honest so thanks! Do i need to delete all of my original code?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to delete everything. The methods you have for addition, subtraction, etc are good. One thing on those, remove the Console.ReadLine(). You don't need it there. Instead Read in the two numbers and then use the  Console.Write("{0} - {1} = {2}", numberOne, numberTwo, numberOne - numberTwo);